# Only one Synchronous command is not working in Unattend xml

Tags: installation, operating-systems, xml, unattended, answerfile

I am trying to automate OS installation by creating an answer file. I have included all the settings related to our organization. Only the domain join is not happening via command line in Firstlogon commands, but as I get the desktop it gets executed if given manually.

Can someone please help me with this? I have attached my answer file for reference below. (sensitive information has been edited)

```xml
<unattend
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
<settings pass="windowsPE">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SetupUILanguage>
<UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
</SetupUILanguage>
<InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
<SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
<UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
<UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
<UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DiskConfiguration>
<Disk wcm:action="add">
<DiskID>0</DiskID>
<WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
<CreatePartitions>
<CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>1</Order>
<Type>Primary</Type>
<Size>300</Size>
</CreatePartition>
<CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>2</Order>
<Type>EFI</Type>
<Size>100</Size>
</CreatePartition>
<CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>3</Order>
<Type>MSR</Type>
<Size>128</Size>
</CreatePartition>
<CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>4</Order>
<Type>Primary</Type>
<Size>350000</Size>
<Extend>false</Extend>
</CreatePartition>
<CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>5</Order>
<Type>Primary</Type>
<Extend>true</Extend>
</CreatePartition>
</CreatePartitions>
<ModifyPartitions>
<ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>1</Order>
<PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
<Label>WINRE</Label>
<Format>NTFS</Format>
<TypeID>DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC</TypeID>
</ModifyPartition>
<ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>2</Order>
<PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
<Label>System</Label>
<Format>FAT32</Format>
</ModifyPartition>
<ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>3</Order>
<PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
</ModifyPartition>
<ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>4</Order>
<PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
<Label>Local Disk</Label>
<Letter>C</Letter>
<Format>NTFS</Format>
</ModifyPartition>
<ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
<Order>5</Order>
<PartitionID>5</PartitionID>
<Label>Local Disk</Label>
<Letter>D</Letter>
<Format>NTFS</Format>
</ModifyPartition>
</ModifyPartitions>
</Disk>
</DiskConfiguration>
<ImageInstall>
<OSImage>
<InstallTo>
<DiskID>0</DiskID>
<PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
</InstallTo>
<InstallToAvailablePartition>false</InstallToAvailablePartition>
</OSImage>
</ImageInstall>
<UserData>
<ProductKey>
<Key></Key>
<WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
</ProductKey>
<AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
<FullName>InfraA</FullName>
<Organization></Organization>
</UserData>
</component>
</settings>
<settings pass="offlineServicing">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-LUA-Settings" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<EnableLUA>true</EnableLUA>
</component>
</settings>
<settings pass="generalize">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SkipRearm>1</SkipRearm>
</component>
</settings>
<settings pass="specialize">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
<SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
<UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
<UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
<UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CEIPEnabled>0</CEIPEnabled>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ComputerName>*</ComputerName>
</component>
</settings>
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<AutoLogon>
<Password>
<Value>password</Value>
<PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <Username>InfraA</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>password</Value>
                            <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>InfraA</Description>
                        <DisplayName>InfraA</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Name>InfraA</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>password</Value>
                            <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>InfraG</Description>
                        <DisplayName>InfraG</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Guests</Group>
                        <Name>InfraG</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <RegisteredOrganization></RegisteredOrganization>
            <RegisteredOwner>InfraA</RegisteredOwner>
            <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>true</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>C:\Windows\system32\changepk.exe /productkey VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T</CommandLine>
                    <Description></Description>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>8</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>C:\Windows\system32\wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call joindomainorworkgroup fjoinoptions=3 name="Domain name" username="Username" Password="password"</CommandLine>
                    <Description>Domain Join</Description>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>9</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>C:\Windows\system32\shutdown /r /t 0</CommandLine>
                    <Description>Reboot after domain join</Description>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Description>Control Panel View</Description>
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <CommandLine>reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel" /v StartupPage /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f</CommandLine>
                    <RequiresUserInput>true</RequiresUserInput>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <Description>Control Panel Icon Size</Description>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel" /v AllItemsIconView /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>4</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>cmd /C wmic useraccount where name="InfraA" set PasswordExpires=false</CommandLine>
                    <Description>Password Never Expires</Description>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>5</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>cmd /C wmic useraccount where name="InfraG" set PasswordExpires=false</CommandLine>
                    <Description>Password Never Expires</Description>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Description>Enabling Remote Desktop</Description>
                    <Order>6</Order>
                    <CommandLine>reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f</CommandLine>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Description>Enabling ICMPv4 Rules</Description>
                    <Order>7</Order>
                    <CommandLine>netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" new enable=Yes profile=any</CommandLine>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
            <TimeZone>India Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a domain join in Pass 4 specialize with the component [amd64_Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin_neutral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-unattendedjoin)

Comment: ... and how do you do that?